# How to set the first day of the week in System tray calendar?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, calendar

How to set the first of the week to be Sunday in the Calendar that is displayed in the System Tray of Windows Vista Home Basic. I tried setting the first day of the week to Sunday in Windows Calendar (thinking that it might work) and yet still it displays the first day of the week to be Monday. Moreover there are not settings available on the System Tray Calendar

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using regedit, browse to **HKCU\Control Panel\International**, look for the **iFirstDayOfWeek** key and set the value to **0** for Monday, **1** for Tuesday, **2** for Wednesday, etc ...

Comment: for users with windows 8.1, the correct path is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International`. Also to open registory editor, press `start button + r` simultaneously and type `regedit` .

Comment: For users of Windows 10, @Nishant's comment still holds.

Answer (score 15):

On Windows 10:

- Right-click on the Taskbar Clock area. Choose `Adjust date/time`

  [image]
- It opens a dialog, with a `Formats` section, where there is a display-only summary of options, including `First day of week`. Click the link `Change date and time Formats`

  [image]
- On the dialog that now appears, you can choose what one you want on the `First day of week` combobox.

  [image]

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this exact issue when getting issued a UK-regioned desktop.

You need to go to `Control Panel -> Regional and Language Settings` and pick a region that starts the week on Sunday, like US.

Comment: To add to this: In Windows 7 this is an independent setting and can be found on the "Date" tab when customizing the locale.

Comment: good to know - I haven't had a chance to futz with Win7 yet :)

Comment: and the downvote on this answer is because ...?

Answer (score 4):

Just go Regional and Language Settings, there is a combo box: "First day of week:", and you know what to do next...

Comment: Hard to understand why this was downvoted. It's a reasonable solution, though maybe not the best one.

Comment: very easy: there is no option like that in Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2):

- If you are on windows 10, here are steps :

  1. Right click on the date and time area on the taskbar
  2. click on properties
  3. in the setting screen, on the upper right hand corner, there will be a search box, type : first
  4. You will see the option change the date and time format. Click On that.
  5. on the next screen, first option will be to change the first day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

### Reg script

Adding to `user8228`'s answer:

Create a `.reg` file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[hkey_current_user\control panel\international]

"ifirstdayofweek"="0"

; the change is immediate
```

Either click on it to be imported using graphical confirmation dialog, or use `reg import *.reg` command to do the same from the command-line.

#### Note

- case doesn't matter except in the first line
- `REG_SZ` (string) type is indicated by quotes (`"0"`)
- double quotes are mandatory as single quotes won't work
- `reg` command is the `reg.exe` executable in `%windir%\system32`
- `;` is for adding comments (commenting the line) within the `reg` file

Answer (score 1):

By default, windows will show Sunday to Saturday... if you want to change it to Monday to Sunday follow these steps.

Step-1 Open control panel (Windows button+X, Select control panel (P))

Step-2 In Clock, Language and Region select Change date, time, or number format

Step-3 In formats tab go to the first day of week select Monday (or whatever the 
       day you would like to start your week)

Step-4 Press Apply and OK.

Now check your system calendar. it's done :)